# NSScrollView redraw after setting magnification

Tags: cocoa, osx-mountain-lion, appkit, nsscrollview

I am setting the magnification property on an NSScrollView to perform a zoom (Mountain Lion only) All works fine except that after setting the magnification, the whole view is repainted during scrolling - which makes it jumpy. Even if I set the magnification back to 1.0 the repaint/scroll issue persists. Anyone seen this before - or know a workaround?

Thanks

Craig

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, spent one of my Apple support incidents on this. Apparently it's a known issue (which is not fixed in Mavericks either.) No work around available - other than to use layer backed views - which introduces other issues :-(